A route named 'FormBuilder' could not be found in the route collection
I'm working on the Sitecore form 10.4 and created the signup form after the form building used the form in the page but getting below error.
Server Error in '/' Application.
A route named 'FormBuilder' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name
Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: A route named 'FormBuilder' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name

Source Error:


Line 4:  
Line 5:  @{
Line 6:      using (Html.BeginRenderRouteForm(Model, IsPost))
Line 7:      {
Line 8:          @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\local.dev.local\Views\FormBuilder\Form.cshtml    Line: 6

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentException: A route named 'FormBuilder' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name]
   System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, String name, RouteValueDictionary values) +458
   System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.GetVirtualPathForArea(RouteCollection routes, RequestContext requestContext, String name, RouteValueDictionary values, Boolean& usingAreas) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RouteCollection routeCollection, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues) +148
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginRouteForm(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, FormMethod method, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +69
   Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Pipelines.RenderForm.BuildForm.Process(RenderFormEventArgs args) +67
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter) +161
   Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html.HtmlExtensions.BeginRenderRouteForm(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, FormViewModel model, Boolean isPost) +302
   ASP._Page_Views_FormBuilder_Form_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\local.dev.local\Views\FormBuilder\Form.cshtml:6
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +698



I can see from other question you are upgrading from 8.2. Im guessing you have not all the necessary Dlls or config from the vanilla solution.

this is not upgrade project. This is different

Please check your website bin folder and ensure you have all the necessary DLLs for sitecore forms.
These are:

Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Analytics
Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client
Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.SqlServer
Sitecore.ExperienceForms
Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc
Sitecore.ExperienceForms.SubmitActions

The most important of these in your situation is Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc. Reason being, this is where the route FormBuilder is initialized (which is what your error message is complaining about).
public class InitializeRoutes : InitializeRoutes
{
    protected override void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes, PipelineArgs args)
    {
        routes.MapRoute("FormBuilder", "formbuilder/{action}/{id}", new
        {
            controller = "FormBuilder",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
        routes.MapRoute("FieldTracking", "fieldtracking/{action}", new
        {
            controller = "FieldTracking",
            action = "Register"
        });
    }
}

Also, ensure you have the correct version of the OTB config. If you look in  App_Config\Sitecore\ExperienceForms\Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.config.
The file should contain:
<pipelines>
  <initialize>
    <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />

